# http: ContentLength=105 with Body length 0

Tags: http, go, client

I'm trying to get data from es via http request, but after passing rquest body, this error appears:

> http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:13995: Get
> "http://127.0.0.1:9200/demo/_search": http: ContentLength=105 with
> Body length 0

> `ab -c 100 -n 3000 http://127.0.0.1:9090/q`

```golang
var (
    url  = "http://127.0.0.1:9200/demo/_search"
    payload = `{"_source":false,"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"term":{"hello":"world"}}]}},"sort":[],"from":0,"size":10}`
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/q", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        _, _ = w.Write(doQuery(url, payload))
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil))
}

func doQuery(url, payload string) (result []byte) {
    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, strings.NewReader(payload))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    request.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    request.Header.Add("Connection", "close")

    client := &http.Client{}
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()
    result, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    return result
}
```

I've tried two ways, and it works:

- remove request body.
- add a mutex around `client.Do()`

How can I fix this without a mutex?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, strings.NewReader(payload))
> ```

You are trying to do a GET request with a non-zero body. A GET request is not supposed to have a body. Use a POST request if you need to send a body.